# Add a treeview item and restore tree status

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

This is my usecase: I've a treeview and I'm navigating them. At a certain moment I add programmatically an item.

At the moment after the item is added the tree completely collapse. 
I'd like rather to have the same situation that was before the adding (the previous selected item still selected).

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you adding them exactly? I saw your tags specify WPF and MVVM but are you using it like a winforms tree by adding treenodes ore are you doing it the MVVM way?
From my experience the tree shouldn't collapse when adding items unless you are completely reloading the whole thing every time you add something.

I can probably provide an example if you specify what you are doing exactly

Comment: Clearly, you've done something wrong in your code, but we can't help you because you didn't show us any code. Please think *before* you ask a question and supply all of the information required to fix your problem... please help us to help you.

Comment: As I said, I add programmatically: I update the itemsource property of the tree, adding an element to this itemsource (a IEnumerable<MyObject>). I don't understand which information is missing